# Not connecting to BLE Device? Using bleak: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ConnectionStatusChanged'"

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to make a very simple program to connect to a [NXP QN9080](https://www.nxp.com/products/wireless/bluetooth-low-energy/qn908x-ultra-low-power-bluetooth-low-energy-system-on-chip-solution:QN9080) via BLE, receive some data, and just print it out. However, I keep getting the following error midway through the connection process:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ConnectionStatusChanged'

I am able to discover the device and see its MAC address with the following code block (provided as an example from the bleak readme):

```
import asyncio
from bleak import discover

async def run():
    devices = await discover()
    for d in devices:
        print(d)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

But when I attempt to run the following code (also from bleak examples), it errors out:

```
import asyncio
import platform

from bleak import BleakClient


async def print_services(mac_addr: str, loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop):
    async with BleakClient(mac_addr, loop=loop) as client:
        svcs = await client.get_services()
        print("Services:", svcs)


mac_addr = DEVICE_MAC_ADDR
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(print_services(mac_addr, loop))
```

The connect function used by BleakClient on init is the following:

```
    async def connect(self, **kwargs) -> bool:
        """Connect to the specified GATT server.

        Keyword Args:
            timeout (float): Timeout for required ``discover`` call. Defaults to 2.0.

        Returns:
            Boolean representing connection status.

        """
        # Try to find the desired device.
        devices = await discover(timeout=kwargs.get("timeout", 10.0), loop=self.loop)

        sought_device = list(
            filter(lambda x: x.address.upper() == self.address.upper(), devices)
        )

        if len(sought_device):
            self._device_info = sought_device[0].details
        else:
            raise BleakError(
                "Device with address {0} was " "not found.".format(self.address)
            )
        logger.debug("Connecting to BLE device @ {0}".format(self.address))

        args = [UInt64(self._device_info.BluetoothAddress)]
        if self._address_type is not None:
            args.append(
                BluetoothAddressType.Public
                if self._address_type == "public"
                else BluetoothAddressType.Random
            )
        self._requester = await wrap_IAsyncOperation(
            IAsyncOperation[BluetoothLEDevice](
                BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(*args)
            ),
            return_type=BluetoothLEDevice,
            loop=self.loop,
        )

        def _ConnectionStatusChanged_Handler(sender, args):
            logger.debug("_ConnectionStatusChanged_Handler: " + args.ToString())

        self._requester.ConnectionStatusChanged += _ConnectionStatusChanged_Handler

        # Obtain services, which also leads to connection being established.
        services = await self.get_services()
        connected = False
        if self._services_resolved:
            # If services has been resolved, then we assume that we are connected. This is due to
            # some issues with getting `is_connected` to give correct response here.
            connected = True
        else:
            for _ in range(5):
                await asyncio.sleep(0.2, loop=self.loop)
                connected = await self.is_connected()
                if connected:
                    break

        if connected:
            logger.debug("Connection successful.")
        else:
            raise BleakError(
                "Connection to {0} was not successful!".format(self.address)
            )

        return connected
```

So this means that await wrap_IAsyncOperation(*) is returning None for some reason, which causes the error. Everything up to that line seems to be working fine. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: I also have an error with bleak, but on a QN9090:   

bleak.exc.BleakDotNetTaskError: System.Exception: Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio
from bleak import discover

devices = []
async def scan():
    dev = await discover()
    for i in range(0,len(dev)):
        print("["+str(i)+"]"+str(dev[i]))
        devices.append(dev[i])

from bleak import BleakClient

async def connect(address, loop):
    async with BleakClient(address, loop=loop) as client:
        services = await client.get_services()
        for ser in services:
            print(ser.uuid)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(scan())
index = input('please select device from 0 to '+str(len(devices))+":")
index = int(index)
loop.run_until_complete(connect(devices[index].address, loop))
```

Comment: This is my code that worked in Win10 but failed in Mac OS. Which OS you were using?

Comment: did you solve your problem with mac? @shuaigi